# Twin primes C code

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes

I'm trying to print the following series 4 6 12 18 30 42 60 72....up to n in C language. Its logic is simple; we have to print the number such that the preceding and successive number should be prime! But the following code is not looping after printing the 4.  What's wrong in the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n, i, j, p2, k;
    int count1=0, count2=0;
    printf("enter the number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=3;i<n;i++){
        for(j=2;j<i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                count1++;
                break;
            }
        }
        p2=i+2;
        for(k=2;k<i;k++){
            if(p2%k==0){
                count2++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(count1==0 && count2==0){
            printf("%d",i+1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: All prime pairs after 3 and 5 (starting with 5 and 7) take the form 6x±1 for some integer x.  How are you going to determine primality — should you have a function to do that?  You could then step through multiples of 6 and check the primality of the ±1 values, printing if both are prime.  Also, since the values 6x±1 are always odd, you don't need to check for divisibility by 2; and (by construction) they're not divisible by 3 either.  That can speed up the primality checking.  Also, in the first inner loop, you could use `j * j < i` to radically reduce the number of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set counters to 0 at the end of the loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n, i, j, p2, k;
int count1=0, count2=0;
printf("enter the number:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=3;i<n;i++){
    for(j=2;j<i;j++){
        if(i%j==0){
            count1++;
            break;
        }
    }
    p2=i+2;
    for(k=2;k<i;k++){
        if(p2%k==0){
            count2++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count1==0 && count2==0){
         printf("%d ",i+1);
    }
    count1=0; count2=0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is right, just set *count1* and *count2* to **0** at the end of the **outer for loop**.

you can try it this way too. 
 this code is in Java. you can convert it to C . Logic remains the same. 
for `Arraylist` take arrays of fixed length equal to `n`.

```
import java.util.*;
class prime
  {
     public static void main(String[] args){

        int n, i, j, p2, k,o;
        ArrayList<Integer> prime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> series = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int count1=0, count2=0;
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter the number:\n");
           n=s.nextInt();
       if(n<3)
       {
          System.out.println("prime numbers start from 3");
       } 
       for(i=3;i<=n;i++)
       {
        for(j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
           if(i%j==0)
          {
             count1=1;
             break;
          }

       }
      if(count1==0)
      {
        prime.add(i);
      }
      count1=0;
      }

      for(k=0;k<prime.size()-1;k++)
        {

              int prdsr=prime.get(k);
              int sucsr=prime.get(k+1);
              if((sucsr-prdsr)==2)
              {
                  series.add((prdsr+1));
              }

        } 

        for(o=0;o<series.size();o++)
        {
         System.out.print("  "+series.get(o));
        }
    }
}
```